# Retuning value in Java method to a changed object

Tags: java

I was wondering why in the below code, **method1**() and **method2**() behave differently.

If **head** is something like

```
Node head = new Node();
head.next = new Node();
```

**method1** returns non-null Node, but **method2** returns null.

```
   Node method() {
        head = head.next;
        Node node = new Node();
        return node;

    }

    Node method1() {
        Node next = method();
        head.next = next;
        return head.next;
    }

    Node method2() {
        head.next = method();
        return head.next;
    }
```

Comment: the methods are different,.. in this case mostly because the left operand of an assignment being evaluated first and `head` being changed when the `method()` call is evaluated (once before second after left side of assignment) (see [15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1))

Comment: There's more code you didnt post that did it behave differently

Comment: in other words, in `method2()` the `head` used for assignment is not the one used in the `return` statement (BTW: since this seems not to be a double-linked list, changing the head is probably making the original node lost)

Comment: I always thought assignments happen right to left never thought that evaluations happen left to right. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the Java Language Specification version 13, section [15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1), Java will first evaluate the left-hand side of the expression to determine the variable or field to assign, and then it will evaluate the right-hand side of the expression.

> **If the type of the right-hand operand is not assignment compatible
>   with the type of the variable ([§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)), then a compile-time error
>   occurs.**
>
> Otherwise, at run time, the expression is evaluated in one of three
>   ways.
>
> If the left-hand operand expression is a field access expression `e.f`
>   ([§15.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11)), possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses,
>   then:
>
> - First, the expression `e` is evaluated. If evaluation of `e` completes abruptly, the assignment expression completes abruptly for
>     the same reason.
> - Next, the right hand operand is evaluated. If evaluation of the right hand expression completes abruptly, the assignment expression
>     completes abruptly for the same reason.
> - Then, if the field denoted by `e.f` is not `static` and the result of the evaluation of `e` above is `null`, then a
>     `NullPointerException` is thrown.
> - Otherwise, the variable denoted by `e.f` is assigned the value of the right hand operand as computed above.
>
> [..skipping arrays access..]
>
> Otherwise, three steps are required:
>
> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression
>     completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not
>     evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>     for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, is subjected to value set conversion
>     ([§5.1.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.13)) to the appropriate standard value set (not an
>     extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is
>     stored into the variable.

In other words, in `head.next = method()`, first `head` is evaluated, which basically stores the current value of `head` on the stack (or the behavioural equivalent of doing that), only then is `method()` called. So the new value of `head` is not seen. What happens in `method2()` is basically the equivalent of

```
Node localHead = head; // original value of head
localHead.next = method();
return head.next; // value of next field of new value of head (probably null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in `method2` you do call method() that add a node to `head` AND return `head`  then return to method2 and add `head` as next of `head`

You probably want return next instead of head in both methods

Comment: In both cases I'm effectively updating head.next.next to new node, In method1, it's updating correctly. In method2, head.next is getting updated to new node.

Comment: in method2 you are just setting ```head.next = head```